# Adding fields to new Quote from Copy Quote

Tags: acumatica

Hi everyone and thanks in advance. I've added the business account to the Copy Quote filter dialog. When the user clicks Actions > Copy Quote, I want to be able to have them select a business account. When they click Ok to copy, it would update this business account on the new quote. When I try to update the new quote in the event handler, the redirect never happens to move to the copied quote. I've tried a lot of different things, but here is the latest I've tried:

```
    public delegate void CopyToQuoteDelegate(CRQuote currentquote, CopyQuoteFilter param);
    [PXOverride]
    public void CopyToQuote(CRQuote currentquote, CopyQuoteFilter param, CopyToQuoteDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<QuoteMaint>(graph =>
        {
            graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<CRQuote>((cache, args) =>
            {
                if (param != null)
                {
                    string bAccountCode = graph.CopyQuoteInfo.GetValueExt<CopyQuoteFilterExt.usrBAccountId>(param).ToString();
                    BAccount bAccount = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.acctCD, Equal<Required<BAccount.acctCD>>>>.Select(graph, bAccountCode);

                    if (bAccount != null)
                    {
                        CRQuote quote = graph.Quote.Current;

                        quote.BAccountID = bAccount.BAccountID;
                        quote.LocationID = bAccount.DefLocationID;
                        graph.Quote.Update(quote);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        baseMethod(currentquote, param);
    }
```

The business account goes onto the copy quote screen with no issues, and I am able to get the selected business account id and the new quote just fine. But it never redirects to the new quote, and it just brings me back to the original quote. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, I removed the override, and it is still happening, but only when I change the business account on the Copy To Quote window. I'm going to check the DAC.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the base method call in a try catch finally block to intercept potential redirection of base method. In finally block you can redirect manually to the target quote with `PXRedirectHelper` method.

```
QuoteMaint quoteMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();
quoteMaint.Quote.Current = quoteMaint.Quote.Search<CRQuote.quoteNbr>([Target Quote Nbr]);

if (quoteMaint.Quote.Current != null)
    PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(quoteMaint, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.InlineWindow);
```

It seems unlikely but is also a possibility that method `CopyToQuote` is not called from an action event handler. In Acumatica framework you can't redirect from all event handlers, it needs to be initiated by an action call.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, there was some DAC objects interfering with each other. This was my final graph extension that worked.

```
public delegate void CopyToQuoteDelegate(CRQuote currentquote, CopyQuoteFilter param);
    [PXOverride]
    public void CopyToQuote(CRQuote currentquote, CopyQuoteFilter param, CopyToQuoteDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<QuoteMaint>(graph =>
        {
            graph.RowUpdated.AddHandler<CRQuote>((cache, args) =>
            {
                if (param != null)
                {
                    var paramExt = param.GetExtension<CopyQuoteFilterExt>();

                    if (paramExt.UsrBAccountId != null)
                    {
                        CRQuote quote = graph.Quote.Current;
                        if (quote != null)
                        {
                            graph.Quote.Cache.SetValue(quote, "BAccountID", paramExt.UsrBAccountId);
                            quote.BAccountID = paramExt.UsrBAccountId;
                            graph.Quote.Cache.SetValue(quote, "LocationID", paramExt.UsrLocationID);
                            quote.LocationID = paramExt.UsrLocationID;
                            //graph.Quote.Update(quote);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        baseMethod(currentquote, param);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!